# Green's function and strong Markov property for stopped Brownian motion

Tags: probability, reference-request, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, reference-works

Let $X(t)$ be a Brownian motion in $\mathbb{R}^n$, stopped at some fixed time $T$. Is there a notion of Green's function for such a Brownian motion? I am guessing that there is, and $G(x, y) : = \int_0^T p(t, x, y)dt$, where $p(t, x, y)$ is the heat kernel in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Is this correct? Also, where can I find a proof that such fixed time stopped Brownian motions have the strong Markov property?

I am also requesting references where such fixed time stopped motions are discussed. I apologize if these questions are really basic, I am just beginning to learn Brownian motion, and the books I have access to do not discuss such fixed time stopped motions explicitly.

Comment: The Green function formula holds by definition. "a proof that such fixed time stopped Brownian motions have the strong Markov property" This seems direct from the fact that the original process has this property, no?

Comment: @Did I was thinking the same, but was not totally confident. Thanks for clarifying!